# Using radio buttons in a ng-repeat loop seems to get the model mixed up

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using some radios buttons for a form.

They represent a boolean and they come in pair, one to set the model value at true, and the other at false. Alone, they work perfectly, but the opposite doesn't seems to work :(

Here's a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/leseulsteve/kckjksbb/

controller:

```
$scope.instructors = [{
    isActive: true
}, {
    isActive: false
}];
```

view:

```
<h2 ng-repeat="instructor in instructors">
   <input type="radio" name="status" ng-model="$parent.instructor.isActive" ng-value="true"/> Active
   <input type="radio" name="status" ng-model="$parent.instructor.isActive" ng-value="false"/>  Inactive
</h2>
```

I read that it has to do with multiple scope for each repeat iteration, but can't get my head around it

Thank you very much again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be a combination of factors:

- For the radio button groups to operate independently, they need to have different names (for example `name="status-{{instructor.id}}"`)
- When written as `$parent.instructor.isActive`, you are not referring to anything having to do with the `instructor` object in the loop; you are actually referring to the key `instructor` on the `$parent` object. So every iteration of the loop will be pointing at the exact same model. Instead, you can use the `instructor` object itself in your `ng-model` attribute: `ng-model="instructor.isActive"`.

I forked and updated the fiddle you linked to: http://jsfiddle.net/0088ab2j/1/

Answer (score 1):

This is actually more of an HTML mistake.

You are assigning all four checkboxes the same name 'status', the browser assumes you want all four checkboxes to work as one.

A simple fix is to change:

```
name="status"
```

to

```
name="{{instructor.id}}"
```

Like so:

http://jsfiddle.net/2da5tz7o/